# How to Check if Selection is in an Outlook Search Folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I use this code to get the selection in Outlook:

```
Dim conversations As Outlook.Selection
Set conversations = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.GetSelection(Outlook.OlSelectionContents.olConversationHeaders)
```

I have to use different methods to loop through conversations, emails etc. and for error handling depending on where the Selection is located.  For example, the process is different for an Outlook Search Folder is different than for a standard folder.

I want to know specifically if the Selection is in an Outlook Search Folder.

Can this be done?

Comment: Check the [`Selection.Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.selection.class).

Comment: Have you checked this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-outlook-item?view=vs-2017

Comment: A possible alternative is to always find the parent folder of the item and process the item there.

Answer (score 0):

This will indicate whether an item, not necessarily the selection, is in a search folder.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SearchFolder_Items()

    Dim acctStr As String
    Dim mailboxStr As String

    Dim objItm As Object
    Dim objFldrItm As Object

    Dim colStores As stores

    Dim oSearchFolders As Folders
    Dim oFolder As Folder

    Dim i As Long

    Dim colItems As Items
    Dim colItemsRes As Items

    Dim srchFldrItm As Object

    Dim subjSingleQuote As String

    Dim subjNoReFW As String
    Dim strFilter As String

    Dim foundFlag As Boolean

    mailboxStr = const_emAddress    '   <-- your "email address" in quotes
    acctStr = Session.Accounts(mailboxStr)

    Set objItm = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)

    Set colStores = Session.stores

    For i = 1 To colStores.count

        If colStores(i) = acctStr Then

            Set oSearchFolders = colStores(i).GetSearchFolders

            If InStr(objItm.subject, Chr(39)) Then

                Debug.Print " objItm.subject.....: " & objItm.subject & " contains a single quote."
                Debug.Print " The restrict filter does not accommodate the single quote Chr(39)"
                Debug.Print "  this way will be slow."

                For Each oFolder In oSearchFolders

                    Debug.Print " SearchFolder.......: " & oFolder.name

                    For Each objFldrItm In oFolder.Items

                        DoEvents

                        If objItm.entryID = objFldrItm.entryID Then

                            Debug.Print
                            Debug.Print objItm.subject & " is in search folder: " & oFolder.name
                            Debug.Print

                            foundFlag = True

                        End If

                    Next

                Next

            Else

                ' Interesting wrinkle just discovered
                ' Must remove "RE: " and "FW: " from subject in search folder
                If Left(objItm.subject, 4) = "RE: " Then
                    subjNoReFW = Right(objItm.subject, Len(objItm.subject) - 4)

                ElseIf Left(objItm.subject, 4) = "FW: " Then
                    subjNoReFW = Right(objItm.subject, Len(objItm.subject) - 4)

                Else
                    subjNoReFW = objItm.subject
                End If

                strFilter = "[Subject] = '" & subjNoReFW & "'"

                For Each oFolder In oSearchFolders

                    DoEvents

                    Set colItems = oFolder.Items
                    Set colItemsRes = colItems.Restrict(strFilter)

                    If colItemsRes.count > 0 Then

                        For Each srchFldrItm In colItemsRes

                            If objItm.entryID = srchFldrItm.entryID Then

                                Debug.Print
                                Debug.Print objItm.subject & vbCr & " in search folder: " & oFolder.name

                                foundFlag = True

                            End If

                        Next

                    End If

                Next

           End If

        End If

    Next

    If foundFlag = False Then

        Debug.Print vbCr & objItm.subject & vbCr & " not found in a search folder."

    End If

ExitRoutine:

    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print objItm.subject & vbCr & " is in folder: " & objItm.Parent

    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "Done"

End Sub
```